# Eliminate IF checks in LINQ deep structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq, if-statement, null

I want to access some deep structures in an XML document using XDocument.

To avoid NULL exceptions, so I have many IF checks like those

```
if(doc.Root.Element("E1") != null)
{
    if(doc.Root.Element("E1").Element("E2") != null)
    { 
        if(doc.Root.Element("E1")
                   .Element("E2")
                   .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id") != null && 
                                         e.Attribute("id").Equals("ABC")) != null)
        {
             var n = doc.Root
                        .Element("E1")
                        .Element("E2")
                        .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id") != null && 
                                              e.Attribute("id").Equals("ABC"))
                        .Attribute("name").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The actual structure is way deeper. Can I eliminate these NULL checks somehow?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/nabuk/archive/2014/03/26/get-rid-of-deep-null-checks.aspx), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672481/cleaner-way-to-do-a-null-check-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple extension method capable of applying a projection to a possibly null value that propagates null values instead of throwing an exception:  (Note that different people like using different names for this operation; feel free to call the method whatever makes the most sense to you.)

```
public static TResult Use<TSource, TResult>(
    this TSource obj, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    where TSource : class
    where TResult : class
{
    return obj == null ? null : selector(obj);
}
```

With this your code can be condensed into the following:

```
var name = doc.Root.Element("E1")
        .Use(element => element.Elements("E2"))
        .Use(elements => elements.SingleOrDefault(
            element => element.Attribute("id")
                .Use(att => att.Value) == "ABC"))
        .Use(element => element.Attribute("name").Value);
```

Comment: Personally - I'd rather see null checks than this.

Comment: @Mike And you're more than welcome to do so in your own code.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any check. You can cast the attribute to `string` then check the equality using `==` instead of using `Equals`.

For elements, you can use [`XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xpathselectelement(v=vs.90).ASPX) instead of selecting them separately like `Root.Element("Foo").Element("Bar")` etc. And then only check the result of the `XPath` query.That will require *less* check at least...

Also it is worth noting that in `C# 6` there will be a [Null propagating operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883) and which allow you to access members of an object safely, then you won't need any of those checks..

Comment: That only gets rid of some of the checks, you still have all of the element checks

Comment: Not really sure why you're getting down voted - a reasonable answer... with a nice tidbit of information for the future.  It kind of demotivates you from wanting to ever assist anyone on here.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
            var n = doc.Elements("E1").DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Elements("E2").DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .FirstOrDefault(e => e!= null && e.Attribute("id") != null && e.Attribute("id").Equals("ABC"));

        if (n != null) {
            string s = n.Attribute("name").Value;
        }
```

Comment: This will throw a NRE if there are no E1 or E2 elements.  `Elements` is also not a valid method to call on the results of your first `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: It won't throw a NRE because I set DefaultIfEmpty(), try this code.

Comment: What do you think `DefaultIfEmpty` will return if there are no elements?  It'll return a sequence of items with a single `null` value.  If you get the first item from that sequence then you'll have `null`, and it'll throw a NRE.  Why don't *you* try the code.  And on top of all of that, it's semantically different, as you're not getting the first element, you're getting a sequence of elements, which isn't what the OP's code is doing.

Comment: The collection has a null element, but I check if it is different from null in FirstOrDefaultPart(e => e != null && ...

Comment: And if you removed the `DefaultIfEmtpy` calls you could remove that null check as there would never be any null values.  But then you still have the problem of not getting just the first element, and instead getting all of the elements.