# Object not created locally

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

I have in my method the snippet below:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
try {
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(is));
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("JSON_NODE");
    String jsonStr = jsonArray.toJSONString();
    return (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(jsonStr);     
}
```

In SonarQube I am getting an issue "Object not created locally" on

```
String jsonStr = jsonArray.toJSONString();
```

I am trying to understand why I am getting this. Any help?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021695/1796579 for an explanation and why there is nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Why violation?

> This violation relates to the fact that method is called on the object
>   which is not created within the method and rather, retrieved as a
>   return object as a result of method invocation on one of the local
>   objects.

Your `jsonArray` Object satisfies above condition.

How to fix ,

See one sample listed [here](http://vitalflux.com/law-demeter-violations-fix/) , your code can be fixed on similar lines.

According to Law of Demeter, a method `M` of object `O` should only call following types of methods :

```
1.Methods of Object O itself
2.Methods of Object passed as an argument
3.Method of object, which is held in instance variable
4.Any Object which is created locally in method M
```