# Null check chain vs catching NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, null, custom-error-handling

A web service returns a huge XML and I need to access deeply nested fields of it. For example:

```
return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt()
```

The problem is that `getFoo()`, `getBar()`, `getBaz()` may all return `null`.

However, if I check for `null` in all cases, the code becomes very verbose and hard to read. Moreover, I may miss the checks for some of the fields.

```
if (wsObject.getFoo() == null) return -1;
if (wsObject.getFoo().getBar() == null) return -1;
// maybe also do something with wsObject.getFoo().getBar()
if (wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz() == null) return -1;
return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
```

Is it acceptable to write

```
try {
    return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
} catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    return -1;
}
```

or would that be considered an antipattern?

Comment: I wouldn't mind the `null` checks that much, since `wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt()` is already a code smell. Read what the ["Law of Demeter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is and prefer to refactor your code accordingly. Then the problem with the `null` checks will be gone as well. And think about using `Optional`.

Comment: What about using **XPath** and leaving it to their evaluation?

Comment: That code is probably generated by `wsdl2java`, which has no respect for the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Catching `NullPointerException` is a **really problematic thing to do** since they can happen almost anywhere. It's very easy to get one from a bug, catch it by accident and continue as if everything is normal, thus hiding a real problem. **It's so tricky to deal with so it's best to avoid altogether.** (For example, think about auto-unboxing of a null `Integer`.)

I suggest that you use the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class instead. This is often the best approach when you want to work with values that are either present or absent.

Using that you could write your code like this:

```
public Optional<Integer> m(Ws wsObject) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(wsObject.getFoo()) // Here you get Optional.empty() if the Foo is null
        .map(f -> f.getBar()) // Here you transform the optional or get empty if the Bar is null
        .map(b -> b.getBaz())
        .map(b -> b.getInt());
        // Add this if you want to return null instead of an empty optional if any is null
        // .orElse(null);
        // Or this if you want to throw an exception instead
        // .orElseThrow(SomeApplicationException::new);
}
```

---

### Why optional?

Using `Optional`s instead of `null` for values that might be absent makes that fact very visible and clear to readers, and the type system will make sure you don't accidentally forget about it.

You also get access to methods for working with such values more conveniently, like [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-).

---

### Is absence valid or error?

But also think about if it is a valid result for the intermediate methods to return null or if that is a sign of an error. If it is always an error then it's probably better throw an exception than to return a special value, or for the intermediate methods themselves to throw an exception.

---

### Maybe more optionals?

If on the other hand absent values from the intermediate methods are valid, maybe you can switch to `Optional`s for them also?

Then you could use them like this:

```
public Optional<Integer> mo(Ws wsObject) {
    return wsObject.getFoo()
        .flatMap(f -> f.getBar())
        .flatMap(b -> b.getBaz())
        .flatMap(b -> b.getInt());        
}
```

---

### Why not optional?

The only reason I can think of for not using `Optional` is if this is in a really performance critical part of the code, and if garbage collection overhead turns out to be a problem. This is because a few `Optional` objects are allocated each time the code is executed, and the VM *might* not be able to optimize those away. In that case your original if-tests might be better.

Comment: Very good answer. It should be mentioned that if there are other possible failure conditions, and you need to distinguish between them, you can use `Try` instead of `Optional`. Although there is no `Try` in the Java API, there are many libs providing one, e.g. http://javaslang.io, https://github.com/bradleyscollins/try4j, http://www.functionaljava.org or https://github.com/jasongoodwin/better-java-monads

Comment: `FClass::getBar` etc would be shorter.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Maybe a little. But I usually prefer lambdas to methods refs because often the class names are much longer, and I find lambdas a little easier to read.

Comment: @Lii fair enough, but note that a method reference may be a tiny bit faster, as a lambda may require more complex compile time constructs. The lambda will require the generation of a `static` method, which will incur a very minor penalty.

Comment: @Lii I actually find method references to be cleaner and more descriptive, even when they are slightly longer.

Comment: @shmosel: It's an interesting question! I think the lack of explicit arguments makes it a little harder to read, there is no clue in the code about what arguments the method takes so you have to remember that. On the other hand the expression `Foo::getBar` immediately tells you that it's a method on a `Foo`, which isn't apparent with a lambda. But on the third hand `getBar` could be a static method, or could take more than one argument, etc, those things are clear with a lambda but not with a meth-ref. I haven't been able to form a strong opinion about which way is best.

Comment: @Lii what would flatmap do in the second case you mention? I don't understand.

Comment: @likejudo: The second example is intended to illustrate how the code would look IF the `getXXX` methods themselves returned `Optional`s, instead of nullable objects. In that case you have to use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: @Lii I dont understand why we have to use flatmap instead of map.

Comment: @likejudo: I think that if you examine the documentation and types of `map` and `flatMap`, copy the code a source file and try it out for yourself then you will understand.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest considering [`Objects.requireNonNull(T obj, String message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,%20java.lang.String)). You might build chains with a detailed message for each exception, like

```
requireNonNull(requireNonNull(requireNonNull(
    wsObject, "wsObject is null")
        .getFoo(), "getFoo() is null")
            .getBar(), "getBar() is null");
```

I would suggest you not to use special return-values, like `-1`. That's not a Java style. Java has designed the mechanism of exceptions to avoid this old-fashioned way which came from the C language.

Throwing `NullPointerException` is not the best option too. You could provide your own exception (making it *checked* to guarantee that it will be handled by a user or *unchecked* to process it in an easier way) or use a specific exception from XML parser you are using.

Comment: `Objects.requireNonNull` eventually throws `NullPointerException`. So this doesn't make the situation any different than `return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt()`

Comment: @ArkaGhosh, also it avoids a plenty of `if`s as OP showed

Comment: This is the only sane solution. All others advise to use exceptions for flow control which is a code smell. On a side note: I consider the method chaining done by the OP a smell as well. If he would work with three local variables and the corresponding if's the situation would be much clearer. Also I think the problem is deeper than just working around a NPE: OP should ask himself why the getters can return null. What does null mean? Maybe some null-object would be better? Or crash in one getter with a meaningful exception? Basically everything is better than exceptions for flow control.

Comment: The unconditional advice to use exceptions to signal the absence of a valid return value is not very good. Exceptions are useful when a method fails in a way which is hard for the caller to recover from and which is better handled in a try-catch-statement in some other part of the program. To simply signal the absence of a return value it is better to use the `Optional` class, or maybe to return a nullable `Integer`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the class structure is indeed out of our control, as seems to be the case, I think catching the NPE as suggested in the question is indeed a reasonable solution, unless performance is a major concern. One small improvement might be to wrap the throw/catch logic to avoid clutter:

```
static <T> T get(Supplier<T> supplier, T defaultValue) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
return get(() -> wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt(), -1);
```

Comment: `return get(() -> wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt(), "");` does not give an error in compile time which could be problematic.

Comment: Sure it does: https://ideone.com/X8rKiO

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in the comment,

Following statement disobeys the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter),

```
wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt()
```

What you want is `int` and you can get it from `Foo`. *Law of Demeter* says, *never talk to the strangers*. For your case you can hide the actual implementation under the hood of `Foo` and `Bar`.

Now, you can create method in `Foo` to fetch `int` from `Baz`. Ultimately, `Foo` will have `Bar` and in `Bar` we can access `Int` without exposing `Baz` directly to `Foo`. So, null checks are probably divided to different classes and only required attributes will be shared among the classes.

Comment: It is debatable if it's disobeyes the Law Of Demeter since the WsObject is probably only a data structure. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021695/1528880

Comment: @DerM Yes, that is possible, but since OP already has something that parses his XML file, he can also think about creating suitable model classes for required tags, so the parsing library can map them. Then these model classes contain the logic for a `null` check of its own sub tags.

Answer (score 4):

My answer goes almost in the same line as @janki, but I would like to modify the code snippet slightly as below:

```
if (wsObject.getFoo() != null && wsObject.getFoo().getBar() != null && wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz() != null) 
   return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
else
   return something or throw exception;
```

You can add a null check for `wsObject` as well, if there's any chance of that object being null.

Answer (score 4):

You say that some methods "may return `null`" but do not say in what circumstances they return `null`. You say you catch the `NullPointerException` but you do not say why you catch it. This lack of information suggests you do not have a clear understanding of what exceptions are for and why they are superior to the alternative.

Consider a class method that is meant to perform an action, but the method can not *guarantee* it will perform the action, because of circumstances beyond its control (which is in fact [the case for *all* methods in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8729011/545127)). We call that method and it returns. The code that calls that method needs to know whether it was successful. How can it know? How can it be structured to cope with the two possibilities, of success or failure?

Using exceptions, we can write methods that have **success as a post condition**. If the method returns, it was successful.  If it throws an exception, it had failed. This is a big win for clarity. We can write code that clearly processes the normal, success case, and move all the error handling code into `catch` clauses. It often transpires that the details of how or why a method was unsuccessful are not important to the caller,  so the same `catch` clause can be used for handling several types of failure. And it often happens that a method does not need to catch exceptions *at all*, but can just allow them to propagate to *its* caller. Exceptions due to program bugs are in that latter class; few methods can react appropriately when there is a bug.

So, those methods that return `null`.

- Does a `null` value indicate a bug in your code? If it does, you should not be catching the exception at all. And your code should not be trying to second guess itself. Just write what is clear and concise on the assumption that it will work. Is a chain of method calls clear and concise? Then just use them.
- Does a `null` value indicate invalid input to your program? If it does, a `NullPointerException` is not an appropriate exception to throw,  because conventionally it is reserved for indicating bugs. You probably want to throw a custom exception derived from `IllegalArgumentException` (if you want an [unchecked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions)) or `IOException` (if you want a checked exception). Is your program required to provide detailed syntax error messages when there is invalid input? If so, checking each method for a `null` return value then throwing an appropriate diagnostic exception is the only thing you can do. If your program need not provide detailed diagnostics, chaining the method calls together, catching any `NullPointerException` and then throwing your custom exception is clearest and most concise.

---

One of the answers claims that the chained method calls violate the [*Law of Demeter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and thus are bad. That claim is mistaken.

- When it comes to program design, there are not really any absolute rules about what is good and what is bad. There are only heuristics: rules that are right much (even almost all) of the time. Part of the skill of programming is knowing when it is OK to break those kinds of rules. So a terse assertion that "this is against rule *X*" is not really an answer at all. Is this one of the situations where the rule *should* be broken?
- The *Law of Demeter* is really a rule about API or class interface design. When designing classes, it is useful to have a *hierarchy of abstractions*. You have low level classes that uses the language primitives to directly perform operations and represent objects in an abstraction that is higher level than the language primitives. You have medium level classes that delegate to the low level classes, and implement operations and representations at a higher level than the low level classes. You have high level classes that delegate to the medium level classes, and implement still higher level operations and abstractions. (I've talked about just three levels of abstraction here, but more are possible). This allows your code to express itself in terms of appropriate abstractions at each level, thereby hiding complexity. The rationale for the *Law of Demeter* is that if you have a chain of method calls, that suggests you have a high level class reaching in through a medium level class to deal directly with low level details, and therefore that your medium level class has not provided a medium-level abstract operation that the high level class needs. But it seems that is *not* the situation you have here: you did not design the classes in the chain of method calls, they are the result of some auto-generated XML serialization code (right?), and the chain of calls is not descending through an abstraction hierarchy because the des-serialized XML is all at the same level of the abstraction hierarchy (right?)?

Answer (score 3):

To improve readability, you may want to use multiple variables, like

```
Foo theFoo;
Bar theBar;
Baz theBaz;

theFoo = wsObject.getFoo();

if ( theFoo == null ) {
  // Exit.
}

theBar = theFoo.getBar();

if ( theBar == null ) {
  // Exit.
}

theBaz = theBar.getBaz();

if ( theBaz == null ) {
  // Exit.
}

return theBaz.getInt();
```

Comment: This is far less readable in my opinion. It litters the method with a whole bunch of null-checking logic which is completely irrelevant from the actual logic of the method.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, respecting the Law of Demeter is definitely part of the solution.  Another part, wherever possible, is to change those chained methods so they cannot return `null`.  You can avoid returning `null` by instead returning an empty `String`, an empty `Collection`, or some other dummy object that means or does whatever the caller would do with `null`.

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` is a run-time exception, so generally speaking is not recommended to catch it, but to avoid it.

You will have to catch the exception wherever you want to call the method (or it will propagate up the stack). Nevertheless, if in your case you can keep working with that result with value -1 and you are sure that it won't propagate because you are not using any of  the "pieces" that may be null, then it seems right to me to catch it

**Edit:**

I agree with the later [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960855/6378311) from @xenteros, it wil be better to launch your own exception instead returning -1 you can call it `InvalidXMLException` for instance.

Comment: What do you mean with "no matter if you catch it, it can propagate to other parts of the code"?

Comment: If the null is in this sentence wsObject.getFoo()

And in later parts of the code you run again that query or use wsObject.getFoo().getBar() (for instance) it will raise again a NullPointerException.

Comment: That is an unusual wording for "You will have to catch the exception wherever you want to call the method (or it will propagate up the stack)." if I understand correctly. I agree with that (and that may be a problem), I just find the wording to be confusing.

Comment: I'll fix it, sorry, English is not my first language so this may happen sometimes :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't catch `NullPointerException`. You don't know where it is coming from (I know it is not probable in your case but *maybe* something else threw it) and it is slow.
You want to access the specified field and for this every other field has to be not null. This is a perfect valid reason to check every field. I would probably check it in one if and then create a method for readability. As others pointed out already returning -1 is very oldschool but I don't know if you have a reason for it or not (e.g. talking to another system).

```
public int callService() {
    ...
    if(isValid(wsObject)){
        return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
    }
    return -1;
}


public boolean isValid(WsObject wsObject) {
    if(wsObject.getFoo() != null &&
        wsObject.getFoo().getBar() != null &&
        wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: It is debatable if it's disobeyes the Law Of Demeter since the WsObject is probably only a data structure (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021695/1528880).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to refactor the code and you can use Java 8, it is possible to use Method references.

A simple demo first (excuse the static inner classes)

```
public class JavaApplication14 
{
    static class Baz
    {
        private final int _int;
        public Baz(int value){ _int = value; }
        public int getInt(){ return _int; }
    }
    static class Bar
    {
        private final Baz _baz;
        public Bar(Baz baz){ _baz = baz; }
        public Baz getBar(){ return _baz; }   
    }
    static class Foo
    {
        private final Bar _bar;
        public Foo(Bar bar){ _bar = bar; }
        public Bar getBar(){ return _bar; }   
    }
    static class WSObject
    {
        private final Foo _foo;
        public WSObject(Foo foo){ _foo = foo; }
        public Foo getFoo(){ return _foo; }
    }
    interface Getter<T, R>
    {
        R get(T value);
    }

    static class GetterResult<R>
    {
        public R result;
        public int lastIndex;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WSObject wsObject = new WSObject(new Foo(new Bar(new Baz(241))));
        WSObject wsObjectNull = new WSObject(new Foo(null));

        GetterResult<Integer> intResult
                = getterChain(wsObject, WSObject::getFoo, Foo::getBar, Bar::getBar, Baz::getInt);

        GetterResult<Integer> intResult2
                = getterChain(wsObjectNull, WSObject::getFoo, Foo::getBar, Bar::getBar, Baz::getInt);


        System.out.println(intResult.result);
        System.out.println(intResult.lastIndex);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(intResult2.result);
        System.out.println(intResult2.lastIndex);

        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public static <R, V1, V2, V3, V4> GetterResult<R>
            getterChain(V1 value, Getter<V1, V2> g1, Getter<V2, V3> g2, Getter<V3, V4> g3, Getter<V4, R> g4)
            {
                GetterResult result = new GetterResult<>();

                Object tmp = value;


                if (tmp == null)
                    return result;
                tmp = g1.get((V1)tmp);
                result.lastIndex++;


                if (tmp == null)
                    return result;
                tmp = g2.get((V2)tmp);
                result.lastIndex++;

                if (tmp == null)
                    return result;
                tmp = g3.get((V3)tmp);
                result.lastIndex++;

                if (tmp == null)
                    return result;
                tmp = g4.get((V4)tmp);
                result.lastIndex++;


                result.result = (R)tmp;

                return result;
            }
}
```

Output

> 241
>   4
>
> null
>   2

The interface `Getter` is just a functional interface, you may use any equivalent.
`GetterResult` class, accessors stripped out for clarity, hold the result of the getter chain, if any, or the index of the last getter called.

The method `getterChain` is a simple, boilerplate piece of code, that can be generated automatically (or manually when needed).
I structured the code so that the repeating block is self evident.

---

This is not a perfect solution as you still need to define one overload of `getterChain` per number of getters.

I would refactor the code instead, but if can't and you find your self using long getter chains often you may consider building a class with the overloads that take from 2 to, say, 10, getters.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add an answer which focus on the **meaning of the error**. Null exception in itself doesn't provide any meaning full error. So I'd advise to avoid dealing with them directly.

There is a thousands cases where your code can go wrong: cannot connect to database, IO Exception, Network error... If you deal with them one by one (like the null check here), it would be too much of a hassle.

In the code:

```
wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
```

Even when you know which field is null, you have no idea about what goes wrong. Maybe Bar is null, but is it expected? Or is it a data error? Think about people who read your code

Like in xenteros's answer, I'd propose using **custom unchecked exception**. For example, in this situation: Foo can be null (valid data), but Bar and Baz should never be null (invalid data)

The code can be re-written:

```
void myFunction()
{
    try 
    {
        if (wsObject.getFoo() == null)
        {
          throw new FooNotExistException();
        }

        return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.error(ex.Message, ex); // Write log to track whatever exception happening
        throw new OperationFailedException("The requested operation failed")
    }
}


void Main()
{
    try
    {
        myFunction();
    }
    catch(FooNotExistException)
    {
        // Show error: "Your foo does not exist, please check"
    }
    catch(OperationFailedException)
    {
        // Show error: "Operation failed, please contact our support"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unchecked exceptions indicate that the programmer is misusing the API.  External problems like "cannot connect to database, IO Exception, Network error" should be indicated by checked exceptions.

Comment: It really depends on the need of the caller. Checked exception help because it force you to process the error. However, in other cases, it is not necessary and may pollute the code. For example, you have an IOException in your Data layer, will you throw it to Presentation layer? That'd mean you have to catch the exception and re-throw at every caller. I'd prefer wrap the IOException by a custom BusinessException, with a relevant message, and let it pop through the stacktrace, until a global filter catch it and display the message to user.

Comment: Callers don't have to catch and re-throw checked exceptions, just declare them to be thrown.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: you are correct, we only need to declare the exception to be thrown. We still need to declare though.
Edit: Taking a 2nd look at it, there are quite a lot of debates about checked vs unchecked exception usages (eg: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/is-it-good-practice-to-catch-a-checked-exception-and-throw-a-runtimeexception).

Answer (score 2):

Have been following this post since yesterday.

I have been commenting/voting the comments which says, catching NPE is bad. Here is why I have been doing that.

```
package com.todelete;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setSomeCrap(null);
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setAddress(address);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(person.getAddress().getSomeCrap().getCrap());
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

            }
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime - startTime) / 1000F);
        long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            if (person != null) {
                Address address1 = person.getAddress();
                if (address1 != null) {
                    SomeCrap someCrap2 = address1.getSomeCrap();
                    if (someCrap2 != null) {
                        System.out.println(someCrap2.getCrap());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime1 - startTime1) / 1000F);
    }
}
```

---

```
  public class Person {
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.todelete;

public class Address {
    private SomeCrap someCrap;

    public SomeCrap getSomeCrap() {
        return someCrap;
    }

    public void setSomeCrap(SomeCrap someCrap) {
        this.someCrap = someCrap;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.todelete;

public class SomeCrap {
    private String crap;

    public String getCrap() {
        return crap;
    }

    public void setCrap(String crap) {
        this.crap = crap;
    }
}
```

*Output*

3.216

0.002

I see a clear winner here. Having if checks is way too less expensive than catch an exception. I have seen that Java-8 way of doing. Considering that 70% of the current applications still run on Java-7 I am adding this answer.

**Bottom Line** For any mission critical applications, handling NPE is costly.

Comment: Three extra seconds on one million requests *in the worst case* is measurable, but it would rarely be a deal breaker, even in "mission critical applications". There are systems where adding 3.2 microseconds to a request is a big deal, and if you have such a system, by all means think carefully about exceptions. But calling a web service and deserializing its output, per the original question, probably takes much longer than that, and worrying about the performance of exception handling is beside the point there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: 3 Seconds per check/Million. So, the number of checks will increase the cost

Comment: True. Even with that I'd still consider it a case of "profile first", though. You'd need over 300 checks in one request before the request takes a full millisecond extra. Design considerations would weigh on my soul far sooner than that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: :) Agreed! I would like to leave it up to the programmer with the result and let them take a call!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth considering to create your own Exception. Let's call it MyOperationFailedException. You can throw it instead returning a value. The result will be the same - you'll quit the function, but you won't return hard-coded value -1 which is Java anti-pattern. In Java we use Exceptions.

```
try {
    return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
} catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    throw new MyOperationFailedException();
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to the discussion in comments let me add something to my previous thoughts. In this code there are two possibilities. One is that you accept null and the other one is, that it is an error.

If it's an error and it occurs, You can debug your code using other structures for debugging purposes when breakpoints aren't enough.

If it's acceptable, you don't care about where this null appeared. If you do, you definitely shouldn't chain those requests.

Comment: Don't you think it's a bad idea to suppress the exception? In realtime, if we lose the trace of an exception, its real pain in the bottom to find out what the hell is going on! I would always suggest not to use chaining. The second problem I see is : This code can't grantee at point of time, which of the result was null.

Comment: Nope, your Exception can have a message which would certainly point the place where it was thrown. I agree chaining isn't the best solution :)

Comment: Nope, it would just say about the line number. So, any of the calls in the chain may lead to an exception.

Comment: "If it's an error and it occurs, You can debug your code" - not in production. I'd much rather know WHAT failed when all I have is a log than trying to divine what happened to cause it to fail. With that advise (and that code), all you really know is that one of 4 things was null, but not which one or why.

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is an issue then the 'catch' option should be considered.
If 'catch' cannot be used because it would propagate (as mentioned by 'SCouto') then use local variables to avoid multiple calls to methods `getFoo()`, `getBar()` and `getBaz()`.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have is lengthy, but very readable.  If I were a new developer coming to your code base I could see what you were doing fairly quickly.  Most of the other answers (including catching the exception) don't seem to be making things more readable and some are making it less readable in my opinion.

Given that you likely don't have control over the generated source and assuming you truly just need to access a few deeply nested fields here and there then I would recommend wrapping each deeply nested access with a method.

```
private int getFooBarBazInt() {
    if (wsObject.getFoo() == null) return -1;
    if (wsObject.getFoo().getBar() == null) return -1;
    if (wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz() == null) return -1;
    return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
}
```

If you find yourself writing a lot of these methods or if you find yourself tempted to make these public static methods then I would create a separate object model, nested how you would like, with only the fields you care about, and convert from the web services object model to your object model.

When you are communicating with a remote web service it is very typical to have a "remote domain" and an "application domain" and switch between the two.  The remote domain is often limited by the web protocol (for example, you can't send helper methods back and forth in a pure RESTful service and deeply nested object models are common to avoid multiple API calls) and so not ideal for direct use in your client.

For example:

```
public static class MyFoo {

    private int barBazInt;

    public MyFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.barBazInt = parseBarBazInt();
    }

    public int getBarBazInt() {
        return barBazInt;
    }

    private int parseFooBarBazInt(Foo foo) {
        if (foo() == null) return -1;
        if (foo().getBar() == null) return -1;
        if (foo().getBar().getBaz() == null) return -1;
        return foo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return wsObject.getFooBarBazInt();
```

by applying the the Law of Demeter,

```
class WsObject
{
    FooObject foo;
    ..
    Integer getFooBarBazInt()
    {
        if(foo != null) return foo.getBarBazInt();
        else return null;
    }
}

class FooObject
{
    BarObject bar;
    ..
    Integer getBarBazInt()
    {
        if(bar != null) return bar.getBazInt();
        else return null;
    }
}

class BarObject
{
    BazObject baz;
    ..
    Integer getBazInt()
    {
        if(baz != null) return baz.getInt();
        else return null;
    }
}

class BazObject
{
    Integer myInt;
    ..
    Integer getInt()
    {
        return myInt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving answer which seems different from all others.

> I recommend you to check for `NULL` in `if`s.

**Reason :**

> We should not leave a single chance for our program to be crashed.
>   NullPointer is generated by system. **The behaviour of System
>   generated exceptions can not be predicted**. You should not leave your
>   program in the hands of System when you already have a way of handling
>   it by your own. And put the Exception handling mechanism for the extra safety.!!

For making your code easy to read try this for checking the conditions :

```
if (wsObject.getFoo() == null || wsObject.getFoo().getBar() == null || wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz() == null) 
   return -1;
else 
   return wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt();
```

**EDIT :**

> Here you need to store these values `wsObject.getFoo()`, 
>   `wsObject.getFoo().getBar()`, `wsObject.getFoo().getBar().getBaz()` in
>   some variables. I am not doing it because i don't know the return
>   types of that functions.

Any suggestions will be appreciated..!!

Comment: Did you consider getFoo() a very timeconsuming operation? You should store returned values in variables, however it's a waste of memory. Your method is perfect for C programming.

Comment: but sometime is better to be 1 millisecond late then program getting crashes @xenteros..!!

Comment: getFoo() might be get a value from a server located on another continent. It can last any time: mins/hours...

Comment: `wsObject` will be containing the value returned from Webservice..!! The Service will be called already and `wsObject` will get a long `XML` data as a webservice response..!! So there is nothing like **server located on another continent** because `getFoo()` is just an element getting **getter method** not a Webservice call..!! @xenteros

Comment: @xenteros waste of memory - that's certainly not true. The memory is used very good because it supports readability of the code. But I agree that the answer is flawed it the sense you mentioned.

Comment: @MariusK. . I will complete the answer by storing that values in variables but i don't know the type of values returned by these functions : `getFoo`, `getBar`, `getBaz`. the only thing we can get from the question is `getFoo().getBar().getBaz().getInt()` is an Integer.. That is the reason why i have not used variables here..!!

Comment: Well from the names of the getters I would assume they return Foo, Bar and Baz objects :P Also consider removing the mentioned double safety from your answer. I don't think it provides any real value aside the pollution of the code. With sane local variables and null checking we have done more than enough to ensure the correctness of the code. If an exception may occur it should be treated as one.

Comment: You did only half of the edit as the try-catch is still present

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class called `Snag` which lets you define a path to navigate through a tree of objects. Here is an example of its use:

```
Snag<Car, String> ENGINE_NAME = Snag.createForAndReturn(Car.class, String.class).toGet("engine.name").andReturnNullIfMissing();
```

Meaning that the instance `ENGINE_NAME` would effectively call `Car?.getEngine()?.getName()` on the instance passed to it, and return `null` if any reference returned `null`:

```
final String name =  ENGINE_NAME.get(firstCar);
```

It's not published on Maven but if anyone finds this useful it's [here](https://bitbucket.org/richiethom/snag/src/2efc73bfe2e867bcb1f0ddb44b95b3506ab9b874/src/main/java/snag/Snag.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (with no warranty of course!)

It's a bit basic but it seems to do the job. Obviously it's more obsolete with more recent versions of Java and other JVM languages that support safe navigation or `Optional`.