# try..catch VS long if()

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I have a complex model structure in my project.
Sometimes I have to get a *deep* placed value from it. It looks like following:

```
something.getSomethongElse().getSecondSomething().getThirdSomething().getFourthSomething();
```

The problem is that each of those methods could return `null`, and I will get `NullPointerException` in case if it does.

What I want to know is should I write long if like

```
if(something != null && something.getSomethongElse() != null && something..getSomethongElse().getSecondSomething() != null && something.getSomethongElse().getSecondSomething().getThirdSomething() != null && omething.getSomethongElse().getSecondSomething().getThirdSomething().getFourthSomething() != null) {
    //process getFourthSomething result.
}
```

Or it is OK just to use try..catch like following:

```
SomethingFourth fourth = null;

try {
    fourth = something.getSomethongElse().getSecondSomething().getThirdSomething().getFourthSomething();
} catch (NullPointerException e) { }

if(fourth != null) {
    ///work with fourth
}
```

I know that `NPE` is a thing to be avoided, but isn't it overhead to avoid it in my case?

Comment: @shmosel, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can refactor the code and make each method return `Optional`. It will be possible to avoid null checks and try ... catch.

```
Optional<Result> result = something.getSomethingElse()
.flatMap(e -> e.getSecondSomething())
.flatMap(x -> x.getThirdSomething())
.flatMap(e -> e.getFourthSomething());
// at the end to check if result is present
result.ifPresent(..some_logic_here..); // or result.orElse(...);
```

so `getSomethingElse()`  returns `Optional<SomethingElse>`, `getThirdSomething()` - `Optional<ThirdSomething>` and so on. We have to use here `flatMap(Function<? super T,Optional<U>> mapper)` because if the provided mapper is one whose result is already an Optional, and if invoked, flatMap does not wrap it with an additional Optional. In other words if `map` on `map(e -> e.getSecondSomething())` the result type will be `Optional<Optional<SecondSomething>>` and we will have to do unnecessary `get()` call - `map(...).get().map(...)`.

I hope this helps.

***UPDATED***
You can do the same thing using method references.

```
Optional<Result> result = something.getSomethongElse()
            .flatMap(SomethongElse::getSecondSomething)
            .flatMap(SecondSomething::getThirdSomething)
            .flatMap(ThirdSomething::getFourthSomething);
```

Comment: Optinal? You must mean Optional but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960674/null-check-chain-vs-catching-nullpointerexception is much more detailed.

Comment: @user6788933, Thanks a lot for spotting the typo, I will update my answer. I agree that answer in other topic is more detailed. However my goal was just to show how to use Optional in this particular case.