# How to handle Null pointer Exception inside a conditional statement

Tags: android, pointers, exception, null

I'm aware that `getFlightKey` is returning null during the initialising itself. It should be null as I'm using my code to build apks for two types of Users. For one user, "flight Key" is used and for the other, it is not used.

```
else {
            tabletMetadata = new TabletMetadata(new DateTime(), getActiveEmployeeIdentifier()
                    ,getAirFiApplication().getTabletId(),getFlightMetadata().get().getFlightKey()
                    ,flightLegIdentifier, new DateTime(), level,
                    location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) : null,
                    location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) : null, null, level, null, null);
```

`getFlightMetadata().get().getFlightKey()` will be null but how can I add something similar to null check handle this?

Comment: may be `try { // your code } catch (NullPointerException npe){ // handle it here }`   ?

Comment: Isn't it bad to catch NPEs.

Comment: Well is this better ? `assert getFlightMetadata().get().getFlightKey() != null` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to handle both the condition with the same piece of code you can do something like this

```
  String value="";
    try{
             value = getFlightMetadata().get().getFlightKey();
        }catch (NullPointerException e)
        {

        }
```

now, relace `getFlightMetadata().get().getFlightKey()` this with `value` and it will not be null instead it will have blank value or no value but will not be null.

Comment: it's not good solution. catching NPE is something to be avoided.

Comment: yes but by the information he has provided or the way he has coded this looks the better fix as if it won't has any value then it will be null or it will has some value. So you should have to check for the occurrence of null pointer exception

Comment: Here is my question, which is similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991307/try-catch-vs-long-if.