# How to perfectly catch the Java NullPointerException in o = objectA.objectB.objectC operation?

Tags: java, android

Not like C or C++, `o =  objectA.objectB.objectC` will throw a `NullPointerException` if either object(A, B) is null in Java. In Java 1.7, I can't do anything like lambda expression to run this command with `try-catch` protection.

So, how will you perfectly cache the exception there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null check chain vs catching NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960674/null-check-chain-vs-catching-nullpointerexception)

Comment: You'd better check if o == null before you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly there is no sort of "propagate null" operator in Java, although it was talked about some while ago. (The notation `o = objectA?.objectB?.objectC` was mooted).

In your case you need to check each part in turn:

```
if (objectA == null){
    o = null;
} else {
   /*OType*/ p = objectA.objectB;
   o = p == null ? null : p.objectC;
}
```

Using purely the ternary conditional operator is also a possibility, but that means you need to write `objectA.objectB` in more than one place.

Enclosing the expression around a `try` `catch` block seems crude to me as it could smother legitimate `NullPointerExceptions` if the chain comprises *functions* (although that is a moot point for direct field access). But it is easy to read, and scales better for long chains:

```
try {
    o = objectA.objectB.objectC;
} catch (final java.lang.NullPointerException e){
    o = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how will you perfectly cache[catch?] the exception there?

I hope you mean *avoid* the null exception; not catching it.

You can write a utility that somewhat makes the check easier; i.e. a static utility method that takes variables arguments (array in diguise) and check if all are not null or not.

### Example

```
public static boolean allNotNull(Object... objects) {
    for (Object o : objects) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if(allNotNull(objectA, objectB, objectC))
```

Comment: How does this help for chained values?

Comment: @shmosel No help for chained values, still need to check one by one.

Comment: It doesn't. This is for a quick check for simple references like the one in the example. For chained values, I think any solution other than catching the exception will be re-inventing `Optional`. See the discussion @shmosel posted above. For Java 1.7, I think Guava's `Optional` can help.

Comment: `Optional` would be an awfully bloated solution pre-lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line version after which `o` will either be null or the value of `objectA.objectB.objectC`:

```
Object o = (objectA != null && objectA.objectB != null) ? objectA.objectB.objectC : null;
```

I would also recommend against using try/catch here

Comment: The last check (`objectC != null`) isn't necessary.