# Optional of nullable on something giving NullPointerException

Tags: java

I m trying to use Optional.ofNullable on an a getter that is throwing a NullPointerException :

My code is as follow :

```
Individual individual = null;

Optional.ofNullable(individual.getIndividualName());
```

[image]

Throwing a NullPointerException here is normal since individual is null

I want to find a pretty way to avoid this exception and get null as result of

```
Optional.ofNullable(individual.getIndividualName());
```

The solution in [Null check chain vs catching NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960674/null-check-chain-vs-catching-nullpointerexception) is very heavy. I try it in a jUnit test and takes several seconds to get the result!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `individual` is null and hence the exception.

You should rather have

```
Optional.ofNullable(individual)
        map(Individual::getIndividualName);
```

The above returns `Optional<Type>` where `Type` is the return type of `getIndividualName()`

> The solution in Null check chain vs catching NullPointerException is very heavy. I try it in a jUnit test and takes several seconds to get the result!

It shouldn't be the case You might be doing something wrong