# Get an element from a list in a Nested optional check

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have the following nested null check which. Trying to make it readable via `Optional` but how do I map a first element?

Stuck with following, unsure how to map this line

```
vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0)
```

I am stuck on the 3rd line

```
Optional.of(vo.getSomething)
    .map(Something::getAnother)
    .map(List<Another>::get(0)) // will not work
```

Here is a working null check. I am trying to clean it up with Optional.

```
if(vo.getSomething() != null){
    if(vo.getSomething().getAnother() != null){
        if(vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0) != null){
            if(vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0).getInner() != null){
                if(vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0).getInner() != null){
                    if(vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0).getInner().get(0) != null){
                        return vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0).getInner().get(0).getProductName();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null check chain vs catching NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960674/null-check-chain-vs-catching-nullpointerexception)

Comment: @OleksandrPyrohov the accepted answer there is exactly what the OP is doing, so I presume they are aware of that approach. The question is about how to make `List<Another>::get(0)` work

Comment: This poor design should be fixed not by `Optional`, but by refactoring all that nesting.

Comment: @Kayaman How could we refactor that.. .That is a json response being captured in that structure from an external api...

Comment: @karvai several ways. You don't think it's suboptiomal that you do 6 null checks just to get a single productname?

Comment: @Kayaman It is but unable to see how I could do it considering thats the structure that gets passed back to me. I need to capture all those details which are used in different places. Would be great to get some ideas.

Comment: In the process of copying the code here, seems like you've pasted `if(vo.getSomething().getAnother().get(0).getInner() != null)` twice. Or else you have a redundant branch.

Comment: @karvai well, for example there's [JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481380/is-there-a-json-equivalent-of-xquery-xpath) which would get rid of all null checks in **this** case, as you'd be using a path to access the (possible) data of interest. Other techniques involve mapping the JSON to something simpler before manipulating it in code.

Comment: @Naman That was just a typo on my part here. It's correct in my code.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks will have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lambda expression

```
.map(list -> list.get(0))
```

should work. Some ideas can't be expressed by method references.

`List<Another>::get(0)` isn't a valid method reference while `List<Another>::get` can be.

```
BiFunction<List<String>, Integer, String> function = List::get;
```

The problem with that expression is that it has a constant `0` and you need to pass it explicitly.

However, you could write a static method

```
class ListFunctions {
    public static <T> T getFirst(List<? extends T> list) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

and refer to it via a method reference

```
.map(ListFunctions::getFirst)
```