# does iterator pattern violates law of demeter? ( least knowldge principle)

Tags: java, design-patterns, law-of-demeter

```
class MyCollection {

   Items menuItems;
    ...
   public Iterator createIterator() {
      return new Iterator(menuItems);
   }

}

class Client {

    public someMethod() {
        Iterator iterator = collection.createIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) { //doSomething } 
        // Client is calling iterator's method directly
    }
}
```

above is a simple iterator pattern.

I wonder does Client violates the principle of least knowledge.

Is it inevitable to violate the principle in iterator pattern?

Comment: Well... `Client` violates LoD, `Iterator` doesn't.

Comment: @public_void, where do you think the Iterator pattern might violate the LoD?

Answer (score 0):

Technically the Client does violate the Law as the object(iterator) is neither an instance variable nor a passed argument. However a Collection being a pure data structure they are exempt from this law 
[Law of Demeter with data model objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021140/law-of-demeter-with-data-model-objects)

Comment: *If* you want to do Object-Orientation, you *have to* deal with the Law of Demeter. There is no such thing as "Data Object" or "DTO" in Object-Orientation. That does not mean you absolutely always have to follow it, but there are no categoric exemptions. You *should* always try to follow it.

Comment: I know, it is still wrong. In the same book Uncle Bob also mentions that he does not consider the rules of Object-Orientation binding. I consider Uncle Bob a *mixed paradigm* developer, not an Object-Oriented developer. Which might be better or worse is of no consequence for this discussion, but it does mean that Uncle Bob's opinion comes from a different context.

Answer (score 0):

The reason LoD exists is to avoid unnecessary coupling, which makes programs fragile.

> The Law of Demeter says that a method f of a class C should only call the methods of these:
>
> 1. C
> 2. An object created by f
> 3. An object passed as an argument to f
> 4. An object held in an instance variable of C

Since `someMethod()` in `Client` creates the iterator with `createIterator()` (which is in many cases a polymorphic Factory method), it does not violate LoD. Condition #2 allows f to call methods of an object it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [Article on the Law of Demeter](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter/), that explains how and why you should follow it.

In short: The code you showed just stopped right before it violates the LoD.

You can use the iterator, since it is *created* for you. Any object created during your method, even indirectly, you can deal with. So `createIterator()` works, and you may access the `Iterator` object.

The `Iterator.hasNext()` also works for the same reason. It creates a boolean for you, which you may access then.

**However**, technically you may not touch any item you get back with `Iterator.next()`. Since those objects are not created for you, and you have no direct reference on them, touching those objects would actually constitute a violation of LoD.