# Dealing with nulls in as little code as possible

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# so please bear with me! The code I would prefer to write throws a null references if there is nothing in the dictionary, as it should. I'm having to cast it as string as the dictionary returns an object:

```
string mainDirectorsInZim = (string)zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields["main_director"];
```

The code I am having to write to solve that?

```
if (zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields.ContainsKey("main_director"))
  {
      mainDirectorsInZim = (string)zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields["main_director"];
  }
  else
  {
     mainDirectorsInZim = null;
  }
```

I have not an insignificant amount of these to write, and it seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: which part of the first code throwing `NullReferenceException` ? it will only throw if the dictionary is null. Are you sure it doesn't throw `KeyNotFoundException`?

Comment: See if this helps you: [Cleaner way to do a null check in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672481/cleaner-way-to-do-a-null-check-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to reduce the code slightly by using the [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but as serhiyb pointed out in the comments, it wouldn't work due to having to convert the `object` to a `string`.

But this should be slightly more efficient still.

```
string mainDirectorsInZim = null;
object tmp;

if (zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields.TryGetValue("main_director", out tmp))
{
    mainDirectorsInZim = (string)tmp;
}
```

OTOH, you could just initialize your string to `null` to begin with, and eliminate the `else` block, if you happen to find that easier to understand since it's closer to your existing code.

```
string mainDirectorsInZim = null;

if (zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields.ContainsKey("main_director"))
{
    mainDirectorsInZim = (string)zimOrganisation.OrganizationFields["main_director"];
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but probably needs additional variable since second generic parameter is not string (object probably based on OP code).

Comment: But your approach is better since dictionary indexer is called only once.